# Need help Implementing maze into 2d array c++

Tags: c++, arrays, 2d, maze

So Im creating a treasure hunting game where the user moves through a maze with hidden health and traps. The goal is to find the treasure without dying. However, I need to create a map and I have a map I generated. I was wondering if there was a way I could just copy and paste my text based maze into the array without putting it in the main function and instead the drawMap function instead of filling each cell. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
// Header Files
#include <cstdlib>
#include <curses.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>


using namespace std; 

HANDLE console = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE); // For use of SetConsoleTextAttribute()


// Function Prototypes

void titleScreen(); // Prints Title and instructions


void mapCreation( char arr[][12], int level);

void drawMap(char arr[][12]);

bool update(char arr[][12], int &level, int &lives, int &score);


// Main Program
int main ()
    {
    // initialize variables
    int option;
    char baseMap[12][12];
    int level = 1;
    int lives = 3;
    int score = 0;
    bool gameOver = false;
    bool levelCompleted = false;


    SetConsoleTextAttribute(console, 240); // change background to white

    system("CLS");// clears screen in order to remove black background

    titleScreen(); // Display Title

    do // do-while loop starts
    {

    cin >> option; // take in input

        if(option == 1) // temporary option to check for next screen
            {
            //Display Maze

            system("CLS");// clears screen in order to remove black background
            while(gameOver == false)
                {
                 mapCreation( baseMap, level );
                 while(gameOver == false || levelCompleted == false )
                      {
                       drawMap(baseMap);
                       update(baseMap, level, lives, score);
                      }
                }
             }
        }
    while( option !=1); // condition of do-while loop

    system("pause"); // Pause for user, only temporary


    return 0;

   }








void titleScreen(){
    cout << " Welcome to Treasure Hunter!\n\n";
    cout << "In order to beat this game you must find the treasure\n";
    cout << " that is located in the maze. You can move using the \n";
    cout << " arrow keys or WASD.\n\n";
    cout << " Warning! There are traps that will take life away as\n";
    cout << " well as add life! However, they are hidden so be careful!\n ";
    cout << " Goodluck and have fun!\n\n\n\n";


}


void mapCreation( char arr[][12], int level )
    {
      int traps = 0;   
      int lives = 0;
      int treasure = 0;
      int x;
      int y;
        for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
            {
             for(int j = 0; j < 12; j++)
                {
                 arr[i][j] = 0;
                }

            }
        arr[1][1] = '1';
        switch (level)
        {
        case 1:
        arr[0][1] = '|';
        arr[1][1] = '|';
        arr[2][1] = '|';
        arr[2][2] = '|';
        arr[2][3] = '|';
        arr[2][4] = '|';
        arr[0][6] = '|';
        arr[1][6] = '|';
        arr[1][8] = '|';
        arr[2][6] = '|';
        arr[2][8] = '|';
        arr[3][4] = '|';
        arr[3][6] = '|';
        arr[3][7] = '|';
        arr[3][8] = '|';
        arr[4][4] = '|';
        arr[4][6] = '|';
        arr[5][1] = '|';
        arr[6][1] = '|';
        arr[6][3] = '|';
        arr[6][4] = '|';
        arr[6][5] = '|';
        arr[6][6] = '|';
        arr[6][7] = '|';
        arr[7][1] = '|';
        arr[7][6] = '|';
        arr[8][1] = '|';
        arr[8][6] = '|';
        arr[8][8] = '|';
        arr[9][1] = '|';
        arr[9][6] = '|';
        arr[9][8] = '|';
        while(treasure < 1)
            {
              x = (rand() % 10);
              y = (rand() % 10);
             if(arr[x][y] == '0')
               {
                arr[x][y] = 2;
                treasure++;
               }
            }
        while(traps < 2)
            {
             x = (rand() % 10);
             y = (rand() % 10);
             if(arr[x][y] == '0')
                {
                 arr[x][y] = 3;
                 traps++;
                }
            }
        while(lives < 1)
            {
             x = (rand() % 10);
             y = (rand() % 10);
             if(arr[x][y] = '0')
                {
                 arr[x][y] = 4;
                }
            }
        break;

        case 2: // Level 2 Map

        arr[0][9] = '\n';
        arr[1][0] = '|';
        arr[1][1] = '|';
        arr[1][2] = '|';
        arr[1][4] = '|';
      //  arr[1][0] = '\n';
        arr[2][2] = '|';
        arr[2][4] = '|';
        arr[2][5] = '|';
        arr[2][6] = '|';
        arr[2][7] = '|';
        arr[2][8] = '|';
      //  arr[2][9] = '\n';
        arr[3][2] = '|';
        arr[3][4] = '|';
        arr[3][7] = '|';
      //  arr[3][9] = '\n';
        arr[4][7] = '|';
        arr[4][9] = '\n';
        arr[5][2] = '|';
        arr[5][4] = '|';
        arr[5][7] = '|';
      //  arr[5][9] = '\n';
        arr[6][0] = '|';
        arr[6][1] = '|';
        arr[6][2] = '|';
        arr[6][4] = '|';
        arr[6][6] = '|';
        arr[6][7] = '|';
        arr[6][8] = '|';
      //  arr[6][9] = '\n';
        arr[7][3] = '|';
        arr[7][5] = '|';
        arr[7][9] = '\n';
        arr[8][4] = '|';
        arr[9][4] = '|';
     //   arr[9][9] = '\n';
        arr[0][11] = '|';
        arr[1][11] = '|';
        arr[2][11] = '|';
        arr[3][11] = '|';
        arr[4][11] = '|';
        arr[5][11] = '|';
        arr[6][11] = '|';
        arr[7][11] = '|';
        arr[8][11] = '|';
        arr[9][11] = '|';
        arr[10][11] = '|';
      //  arr[11][11] = '\n';
        arr[10][0] = '|';
        arr[10][1] = '|';
        arr[10][2] = '|';
        arr[10][3] = '|';
        arr[10][4] = '|';
        arr[10][5] = '|';
        arr[10][6] = '|';
        arr[10][7] = '|';
        arr[10][8] = '|';
        arr[10][9] = '|';
        arr[10][11] = '|';
        while(treasure < 1)
            {
              x = (rand() % 10);
              y = (rand() % 10);
             if(arr[x][y] == '0')
               {
                arr[x][y] = 2;
                treasure++;
               }
            }
        while(traps < 4)
            {
             x = (rand() % 10);
             y = (rand() % 10);
             if(arr[x][y] == '0')
                {
                 arr[x][y] = 3;
                 traps++;
                }
            }
        while(lives < 2)
            {
             x = (rand() % 10);
             y = (rand() % 10);
             if(arr[x][y] = '0')
                {
                 arr[x][y] = 4;
                }
            }
        break;

        case 3: // Level 3 Map

        arr[1][4] = '|';
        arr[1][6] = '|';
        arr[1][7] = '|';
        arr[1][8] = '|';
        arr[1][9] = '|';
        arr[2][2] = '|';
        arr[2][4] = '|';
        arr[3][0] = '|';
        arr[3][1] = '|';
        arr[3][2] = '|';
        arr[3][3] = '|';
        arr[3][4] = '|';
        arr[3][6] = '|';
        arr[4][6] = '|';
        arr[5][3] = '|';
        arr[5][2] = '|';
        arr[5][6] = '|';
        arr[5][7] = '|';
        arr[5][8] = '|';
        arr[5][9] = '|';
        arr[6][0] = '|';
        arr[6][1] = '|';
        arr[6][2] = '|';
        arr[6][6] = '|';
        arr[7][4] = '|';
        arr[7][5] = '|';
        arr[7][6] = '|';
        while(treasure < 1)
            {
              x = (rand() % 10);
              y = (rand() % 10);
             if(arr[x][y] == '0')
               {
                arr[x][y] = 2;
                treasure++;
               }
            }
        while(traps < 6)
            {
             x = (rand() % 10);
             y = (rand() % 10);
             if(arr[x][y] == '0')
                {
                 arr[x][y] = 3;
                 traps++;
                }
            }
        while(lives < 3)
            {
             x = (rand() % 10);
             y = (rand() % 10);
             if(arr[x][y] = '0')
                {
                 arr[x][y] = 4;
                }
            }
        break;

        case 4:
        arr[3][2] = '|';
        arr[3][3] = '|';
        arr[3][4] = '|';
        arr[3][5] = '|';
        arr[3][6] = '|';
        arr[3][7] = '|';
        arr[4][3] = '|';
        arr[5][3] = '|';
        arr[5][5] = '|';
        arr[5][6] = '|';
        arr[5][7] = '|';
        arr[5][8] = '|';
        arr[6][3] = '|';
        arr[6][5] = '|';
        arr[6][8] = '|';
        arr[7][3] = '|';
        arr[7][5] = '|';
        arr[7][8] = '|';
        arr[8][3] = '|';
        arr[8][5] = '|';
        arr[8][8] = '|';
        arr[9][3] = '|';
        while(treasure < 1)
            {
              x = (rand() % 10);
              y = (rand() % 10);
             if(arr[x][y] == '0')
               {
                arr[x][y] = 2;
                treasure++;
               }
            }
        while(traps < 8)
            {
             x = (rand() % 10);
             y = (rand() % 10);
             if(arr[x][y] == '0')
                {
                 arr[x][y] = 3;
                 traps++;
                }
            }
        while(lives < 4)
            {
             x = (rand() % 10);
             y = (rand() % 10);
             if(arr[x][y] = '0')
                {
                 arr[x][y] = 4;
                }
            }
        break;

        case 5:
        arr[0][1] = '|';
        arr[1][1] = '|';
        arr[1][6] = '|';
        arr[2][3] = '|';
        arr[2][4] = '|';
        arr[2][5] = '|';
        arr[2][6] = '|';
        arr[3][1] = '|';
        arr[3][6] = '|';
        arr[4][1] = '|';
        arr[4][2] = '|';
        arr[4][3] = '|';
        arr[4][4] = '|';
        arr[4][5] = '|';
        arr[4][6] = '|';
        arr[4][7] = '|';
        arr[4][8] = '|';
        arr[4][9] = '|';
        arr[5][1] = '|';
        arr[7][2] = '|';
        arr[7][3] = '|';
        arr[7][4] = '|';
        arr[7][5] = '|';
        arr[7][6] = '|';
        arr[7][7] = '|';
        arr[7][8] = '|';
        arr[8][3] = '|';
        arr[8][6] = '|';
        arr[9][6] = '|';
        while(treasure < 1)
            {
              x = (rand() % 10);
              y = (rand() % 10);
             if(arr[x][y] == '0')
               {
                arr[x][y] = 2;
                treasure++;
               }
            }
        while(traps < 10)
            {
             x = (rand() % 10);
             y = (rand() % 10);
             if(arr[x][y] == '0')
                {
                 arr[x][y] = 3;
                 traps++;
                }
            }
        while(lives < 5)
            {
             x = (rand() % 10);
             y = (rand() % 10);
             if(arr[x][y] = '0')
                {
                 arr[x][y] = 4;
                }
            }        
        break;
        }
    }

void drawMap(char arr[][12])
    {
     for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
        {
         for(int j = 0; j < 12; j++ )
            {
             if(arr[i][j] != 3 && arr[i][j] != 4)
               {
                cout << arr[i][j];
               }
            }
        }
    }

bool update(char arr[][12], int &level, int &lives, int &score)
    {
     bool levelCompleted = false;
     bool gameOver = false;

     return 0; // temporary holder
    }
```

Comment: You may want to write your own code generator, something that reads your map file one character at a time and generates a corresponding line of code depending on the character it found. That way you could design your maps in a text editor and have them converted automatically to code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define your mazes as 2D array of strings, stored as a global variable something like this:

```
#define LEVEL_COUNT (2)
const char* maps[LEVEL_COUNT][12] = 
{
    {
        "||||||||||||",
        "|       |  |",
        "|       |  |",
        "|    ||||  |",
        "|          |",
        "|          |",
        "||||||     |",
        "| |        |",
        "| |    |   |",
        "|      |   |",
        "|      |   |",
        "||||||||||||",
    },
    {
        "||||||||||||",
        "|       |  |",
        "|   |||||  |",
        "|       |  |",
        "|          |",
        "|       ||||",
        "|          |",
        "|   |      |",
        "|   |      |",
        "|||||||    |",
        "|          |",
        "||||||||||||",
    },
};
```

Then you can load them into your char array, setting spaces to zero:

```
void loadMap( char arr[][12], int level)
{
     if((level < 0) || (level >= LEVEL_COUNT))
         return;

     for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
     {
         const char* row = maps[level][i];
         for(int j = 0; j < 12; j++)
         {
             if(row[j] == 0)
                 break; // end of string
             if(row[j] == ' ')
                 arr[i][j] = 0;  // set spaces to zero
             else
                 arr[i][j] = row[j];
         }
     }
}
```

Call `loadMap` from your `mapCreation` function after initializing to all zeros (in case any of the strings in the map array are less than 12 chars long and a terminating null is encountered), then apply your randomized traps and treasure placements.

e.g:

```
void mapCreation( char arr[][12], int level )
{
  int traps = 0;   
  int lives = 0;
  int treasure = 0;
  int x;
  int y;
  for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
  {
      for(int j = 0; j < 12; j++)
      {
          arr[i][j] = 0;
      }
  }

  // load the map:
  loadMap(arr, level);

  arr[1][1] = '1';
  switch (level)
  {
    case 1:
    while(treasure < 1)
    {
         x = (rand() % 10);
         y = (rand() % 10);
         if(arr[x][y] == '0')
         {
            arr[x][y] = 2;
            treasure++;
         }
     }
     // etc...
```

Comment: Thank you! However, I have problems actually trying to load the array now. Any ideas?

Comment: What problems are you having?

Comment: Well I have done what you said, but after user input 1 it should load the maze next. However, nothing loads it is just blank. I believe it might have to do with still trying to create the map with case 2. And I also think the treasures are clearing the screen as well. And when you said call it from my mapCreation, do you mean just put it in the main after mapCreation?

Comment: No, I mean call it from inside your mapCreation function. See edit to the answer.

Comment: Oh ok.. I thought you weren't called to call a function inside a function?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Calling a function inside a function is fine, and you are already doing it.

Comment: Oh ok! It's just that in my class they told us it's not possible to call functions inside functions in c++. And so far I am still not getting anything to print out. However, if I delete the treasures, traps, and lives I get the maze that prints infinitely.

Comment: You're not getting anything to print out because your program is stuck in a loop setting the traps. Change if(arr[x][y] == '0') to if(arr[x][y] == 0) (no quotes around the zero) When you print out the maze do you want the empty spaces to display as zeros or spaces or what? You'll have to change your DrawMap function to handle the squares that are set to zero. The maze is printing infinitely because you are calling DrawMap in a loop

Comment: Inside drawMap you should use if(arr[i][j] != 0) cout << arr[i][j]; else cout << ' ';

Comment: Oh ok! I fixed the loop which now prints only one! Thank you so much! I am so sorry if I caused you any inconvenience or if I caused you to be impatient. I was also wondering how I could make the map have a new line in order so it doesnt print out as ||||||||||||||||||| |||| |||| ||| on 2 long single lines. I have tried \n but that doesnt do the trick.

Comment: use cout << endl but put it outside the for(int j.. loop because you only want it to print out once per row

Comment: Ok everything seems good now! Ill see if I can figure out why the treasure, traps, and lives variables are not allowing the maze to be printed because without them, it works fine.